# "adopt a scenario where" or "adopt the scenario where"

Tags: articles, grammatical-number

In this sentence:

> We adopt a scenario where we have four machines.

Is the sentence above correct ? or we should replace `a` by `the` ?

Comment: If prior context (what was being talked about immediately *before* the cited sentence) already mentioned the four-machine scenario (and one or more alternative scenarios) then ***the*** is far more likely (almost, *required*). In all other contexts ***a*** is more likely (but ***the*** would probably always be at least "acceptable").

Comment: Also, the simple present **adopt** might not be the correct choice. It too would depend on the context of the sentence. For example, if you are referring to a decision that has been made, it would be "we will adopt".  If you are referring to an implementation that has taken place, "we have adopted" or if it took place a long time ago, "we adopted".

Comment: You could also say "are adopting".  We would need more context.

Comment: I think both "a" and "the" are possible and it wouldn't be incorrect to use either!

Answer (score 1):

Is there more than one scenario under consideration involving more than four machines? If there is only one, it should be "the", or if there are multiple possible scenarios with four machines and it doesn't matter which it would be "a".